# Is there a fuzzy match for datalist filtering?

Tags: html, html-datalist

`<datalist>` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)) seems to only find an exact match of its entries. As a workaround, I added a canonical version without vowel mutations, but it looks a bit chunky. Is there a better way to make this work? Because nobody searches for "château", everybody just enters "chateau" and expects the result to show up correctly.

[image]

Comment: Seems like what you want is a JavaScript autocomplete or autosuggest

Comment: @j08691 Sure, this would work too. But shouldn't there also be a way with `datalist`? I can imagine this is not such an unusual use case...

Comment: It'd be great, sure. But as of SEP092023 unfortunatley there isn't.

Comment: @j08691 does it have a chance as a feature request for future versions?